# Why would you get NoneType error in python even when explicitly checking if None?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was recently trying to read in a csv, of which one of the columns is serialized as list strings. Using ast.literal_eval usually converts the string to an actual list. In this case, even though we check whether `a` is a list or not, we get back an error saying `None` type is non subscriptable.

Code:

```py
def generate(name):
    df = pd.read_csv(name)
    df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval((x))) # all x should become list
    for a in df['column']:
        if a and isinstance(a, list):
            print(a)[0]
        else:
            print('jey')
```

Error message (the first list is printed)

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.014, 0.0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-d84f295beae6> in <module>
----> 1 generate('parameter_vv/perimeter_log.csv')

<ipython-input-33-e9ee10a439d4> in generate(name)
      4     for a in df['column']:
      5         if a and isinstance(a, list):
----> 6             print(a)[0]
      7         else:
      8             print('jey')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: `print` returns `None`. I think you wanted `print(a[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(a)` return `None` and you see this error when try to do `print(a)[0]`.

I suppose you want to do this instead:

```
print(a[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `print(a[0])` instead of `print(a)[0]`.

---

`print()` returns None, so `print(a)[0]` try to get element 0 from None, this is the error you get.